# Pandas replacing values from a csv with NaN

Tags: python, pandas, mongodb

I have a csv file that I am trying to put into a dataframe with `df = pd.read_csv(data)`. It is a very large dataset(aprox 36000 tweets). When I make the dataframe, some of the values are read as NaN. The data was exported from mongo into csv format. Could this be a problem with the data types ?

Comment: Can you share the data file, or what kind of data returns NaN values?

Comment: Ideally, try to find some rows that are correctly loaded, some that contains unexpected NaN values, and show them **as text with the original separator**

Comment: @Thomas Kok I am using twitter data and the column is that contains NaN is user.follower_count